# Code new variable based on grep return in R

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have a variable `actor` which is a string and contains values like `"military forces of guinea-bissau (1989-1992)"` and a large range of other different values that are fairly complex. I have been using `grep()` to find character patterns that match different types of actors. For example I would like to code a new variable `actor_type` as `1` when `actor` contains `"military forces of"`, doesn't contain `"mutiny of"`, and the string variable `country` is also contained in the variable `actor`.

I am at a loss as to how to conditionally create this new variable without resorting to some type of horrible for loop. Help me!

Data looks roughly like this:

```
|   | actor                                              | country         |
|---+----------------------------------------------------+-----------------|
| 1 | "military forces of guinea-bissau"                 | "guinea-bissau" |
| 2 | "mutiny of military forces of guinea-bissau"       | "guinea-bissau" |
| 3 | "unidentified armed group (guinea-bissau)"         | "guinea-bissau" |
| 4 | "mfdc: movement of democratic forces of casamance" | "guinea-bissau" |
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if your data is in a `data.frame` df:

```
> ifelse(!grepl('mutiny of' , df$actor) & grepl('military forces of',df$actor) & apply(df,1,function(x) grepl(x[2],x[1])),1,0)
[1] 1 0 0 0
```

`grepl` returns a logical vector and this can be assigned to whatever, e.g. `df$actor_type`.

breaking that appart:

`!grepl('mutiny of', df$actor)` and `grepl('military forces of', df$actor)` satisfy your first two requirements.  the last piece, `apply(df,1,function(x) grepl(x[2],x[1]))` goes row by row and `greps` for country in actor.

Comment: Ok so the first part works. I don't quite understand what is going on with the second part though. I don't get what x,x is or where the indices are coming from, what they are selecting. Also, I know apply() takes a function argument, but if grepl() is what we are applying, why is function(x) still in the apply() call. Thanks btw.

Comment: `grepl` takes a single character string as its `pattern` argument.  to compare the country (column 2) to the actor (column 1) you need to `apply` `grepl` to each row with the `pattern=column 2`.  I made an anonymous function to do that and the variable that the function uses is `x`.  Each row of the `.data.frame` are sent to the function as a vector of two character strings which `grepl` evaluates.  Clear as mud I'm sure
!

Comment: No that actually does make sense. Appreciated :)

Comment: Getting an error now: "Error in data$actor1 & apply(data, 1, function(x) grepl(x[13], x[2])) : 
  operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types" as the country variable is a string.